# Welches Geschlecht hat "Quest"?

Tags: etymology, gender

In Rollenspielen gibt es oft das Wort *Quest*, allerdings jedes mal mit einem anderen Geschlecht. Ich habe in verschiedenen Video- und Rollenspielen wirklich jede Möglichkeit gesehen:

Die Quest
Der Quest
Das Quest

Am häufigsten sehe ich eigentlich *die Quest*, aber trotzdem kommen noch andere Varianten vor.

Welches ist das richtige Geschlecht für *Quest*. Gab es das Wort überhaupt schon im Althochdeutschen oder ist es ein modernes, eingedeutschtes Wort?

Comment: für mich ist es auch "die" aber wenn alles benutzt wird ist auch noch alles richtig, bis sich eins durchsetzt.

Comment: Ich höre auch immer wieder "die Queste" (Einzahl, weiblich)

Comment: [**Die** Quest](http://de-en.dict.cc/?s=QUEST)

Comment: "Die Queste" geht gar nicht, "die" ist denke ich das intuitivste. Wie man dann aus "Quest" "Queste" machen kann ist mir ein Rätsel, habe ich aber auch schon gehört/gesehen. Mein Sprachgefühl schreit dazu aber "NEIN"!

Comment: Weitere verwandte [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/5545/1696).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mag sein, dass Quest über das Englische ins Deutsche gekommen ist. Meistens wird es im Deutschen feminin verwendet, Dieses feminine Geschlecht ist dem Lateinischen quaestio(n) zu verdanken, das im 
Altfranzösischen la queste (fem) ist und im modernen Französische la quěte (fem) ist. Ich glaube die Quest ist eine moderne Entlehnung, deswegen das Schwanken im Genus.

Answer (score 6):

Das Geschlecht des aus dem Englischen entlehnten Wortes *Quest* wird - wie üblich bei solchen Entlehnungen - über die gängigste Übersetzung bestimmt. Daher *Die Quest*, wegen *die Suche/die Untersuchung/die Aufgabe/die Wanderung*.

Answer (score 1):

**Quest** ist ein vom englischen *quest* eingedeutschtes Wort und weiblich. Die Variante "*Die Quest*" ist daher die richtige.

Siehe beispielsweise die [Wiktionary-Seite](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Quest).

Comment: @dirkt es hilft, seine vorurteile regelmäßig zu überprüfen ;-). nach einer kleinen recherche und lektüre einer [einschlägigen duden-publikation, spez. S.21](http://www.duden.de/sites/default/files/downloads/Duden_Das_Fremdwort_Lesenswertes_und_Interessantes.pdf), nehme ich meine behauptungen zum grammatikalischen geschlecht von fremd- und lehnwörtern zurück und behaupte das gegenteil. die anderen diesbezüglichen kommentare lösche ich.

Comment: @collapsar: Da das geklärt ist, habe ich meine Kommentare auch gelöscht. Danke für den Link, sehr interessant.

Answer (score 1):

Im [Grimm](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB&lemid=GQ00892#0) gibt es zwei Einträge dazu, dabei wird das Wort als weiblich oder männlich markiert, es schien damals aber so etwas ähnlichens wie *Bettelei* bedeutet zu haben. In beiden Einträgen werden mehrere Jahreszahlen genannt: 1731, 1861, 1482, 1489, 1620

---

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Quest) und [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quest) sind sich in den gegenwärtigen Versionen darüber einig, dass das Wort nur weiblich ist und kein anderes Geschlecht hat.

Allerdings wurde in [älteren Versionen](https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Quest&direction=prev&oldid=499339) des Wiktionary-Beitrags (Dezember 2006 und älter) noch behauptet, das Wort sei rein männlich. (In der [allerersten Version](https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Quest&direction=prev&oldid=396804) vom September 2006 gab es gar keine Angabe zum Geschlecht.)

In Wikipedia wird das Wort seit [24. Oktober 2010 12:41 Uhr](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quest&direction=next&oldid=80657908) als weiblich geführt Am [selben Tag um 11:51 Uhr](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quest&direction=prev&oldid=80659655) war das Wort dort noch männlich. In den allerersten Versionen dieses Artikels aus dem Jahr 2004 fehlt noch eine explizite Angabe zum Geschlecht, allerdings wird z.B. das Wort in der Version vom [31. August 2004](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quest&direction=next&oldid=2363599) im letzten Satz des Artikels in der weiblichen Form verwendet.

---

Das DWDS (Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache) weist dem Wort zwei Geschlechter zu: Weiblich und sächlich, wobei die sächliche Form als *»selten«* markiert ist. Die männliche Form wird dort nicht erwähnt.

Die 5 sichtbaren Referenzeinträge des [Kernkorpus 2000-2010 des DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=korpus21&q=Quest) drehen sich entweder um die **Quest Bay,** wo das Wort *Quest* keinen Einfluss auf das Geschlecht des Begriffs hat, oder um ein Schiff namens *Quest,* was auch nicht weiterhilft, weil alle Schiffe immer weiblich sind. Im Kernkorpus 1900-1999 gibt es ebenfalls 5 sichtbare Einträge. Drei davon beinhalten die Personenamen Martha Quest, Friedrich Quest und Hans Quest, und ein Eintrag besteht nur aus dem Wort *Quest* allein. Ein einzige Eintrag liefert einen Hinweis auf ein weibliches Geschlecht: *»... im Uebergang von der keltischen Peredursage **zur Quest** des heiligen Gral.«*

---

Der [Korpus der Uni Leipzig](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=Quest) beinhaltet 238 Einträge. Die meisten davon liefern keinen Hinweis auf das Geschlecht (*»Was Trainer Olaf **Quest** hier in den letzten Jahren ausgebildet hat, ...«*). Es finden sich aber auch brauchbare Zitate darunter:

- weiblich

> - Natürlich muss auch die Fähigkeit passen, die Sie in der **Quest** einsetzen. ([www.morgenpost.de](http://www.morgenpost.de), gesammelt am 14.01.2011)
> - Beide Fraktionen mussten eine gewisse Anzahl Rohstoffe spenden um die Truppen an der Front zu verstärken, während eine eher kleinere Gruppe sich aufmachte um eine weltumspannende **Quest** zu lösen und schließlich einen Schlaghammer zu erhalten. ([www.op-online.de](http://www.op-online.de), gesammelt am 18.01.2011)

- sächlich

> - Klicken Sie auf die Herzen, um das **Quest** zu starten. ([www.20min.ch](http://www.20min.ch), gesammelt am 18.12.2010)
> - Wenn Sie noch ein bisschen kundiger sind, was dieses Thema anbelangt, haben Sie gute Chancen, unser **Quest** mit Bravour zu bestehen! ([www.20min.ch](http://www.20min.ch), gesammelt am 18.12.2010)
> - Schnell beschleicht den Spieler das Gefühl, dass es das eine oder andere **Quest** weniger auch getan hätte. ([www.krone.at](http://www.krone.at), gesammelt am 11.01.2011)

- männlich

> - Machen Sie den **Quest** rund um die Minderheit, wegen derer die Freizügigkeitsabkommen mit der EU heiss diskutiert wird. ([www.20min.ch](http://www.20min.ch), gesammelt am 18.12.2010)
>   Abhängig von der jeweiligen Rolle verlaufe jeder **Quest** anders, erklärte Electronic Arts. ([www.emsdettenervolkszeitung.de](http://www.emsdettenervolkszeitung.de), gesammelt am 30.12.2010)

Die Anzahl der Einträge mit klar erkennbarem Geschlecht ist auffallend klein. Die meisten Einträge enthalten das Wort als Nachname einer Person oder als Teil eines Spiele Namens, oder in einer grammatischen Konstellation, die das Geschlecht nicht erkennen lässt. Es scheint fast so, als würden die Autoren versuchen zu vermeiden, sich auf ein Geschlecht festzulegen.

Answer (score 0):

Gegen die Theorie, daß "Quest" ein englischer Neologismus sei, spricht die Existenz des deutschen Worts "die Queste" (ein längerer Auftrag, der mit meist mit einem Abenteuer verbunden ist, zB die Suche nach dem Heiligen Gral), die - genau so wie das englische Pendant - vom lateinischen Substantiv "quaerere" (die Suche) oder auch vom Verb "quaere" (fragen) abgeleitet ist. Davon stammt etwa auch das französische "chercher" (suchen).

Siehe etwa [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queste_(Mittelalter))

Comment: Wörter können mehrfach entlehnt werden.