# Why is Mozzarella masculine?

Tags: gender

Mozzarella has a typical feminine Italian/Latin ending (-a).

So is there a specific reason, why it is masculine in the German language? If so, could you please tell me?

Comment: Maybe because it is "der Käse"?

Comment: @Carlster But Mozzarella is a name...

Comment: I was referring to a possible transformation from "der Mozzarella-Käse" to "der Mozzarella".

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/for-new-words-which-are-often-nouns-who-sets-the-gender

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In German *every* cheese name is masculine: "der Parmesan", "der Mozzarella",
"der Ricotta", "der Gouda", "der Camembert", and so on.

Comment: is it a rule or just coincidence?

Comment: Well, it's a rule, but like all "rules" in linguistics, it's descriptive, not prescriptive: A linguistic rule describes what (the majority of) native speakers of a language consider as correct; it does not dictate what they have to consider as correct.

Comment: Could you add the bit that "Käse" is masculine? I think that is the reason why this "rule" exists

Comment: It's the reason why the rule says "all cheeses are male"
rather than "all cheeses are female", but it doesn't explain
why there is a rule at all. There are categories of things for
which there is such a rule (e.g., cheeses, alcoholic spirits),
and others for which there is no rule (e.g., body parts,
currencies, magazine titles).

Comment: Well, the real reason the "rule" exists is, as you correctly said, that people chose to speak that way. And why did they do it? Probably because it is "der Käse" and they just stuck with the gender. The reason why there is no rule for other groups is that people use different genders for members of the group.

Comment: It is not male, it is masculine, that is: of masculine grammatical gender. Not at all the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

The German language is not terribly rational when it comes to assigning gender to various objects. For instance, some parts of the human body are male and some are female, no matter what the overall person owning them is. You should read Mark Twain's essay *The Awful German Language* for a side-splitting take on this. I lent a copy to my German-born teacher, and it came back slightly damp; she had laughed until she cried.

Why is cheese male? Because!

Comment: I didn't mean cheese in general but a special cheese that has a name that should be female.

Comment: 1) This case seems quite rational to me. 2) The "problem" with the body parts applies not only to German.

Comment: Grammatical gender is not "rational" in any language.

Comment: Because cheese is made from the milk of [male cows](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Otis_(Barnyard)) only. ;-)