# Words with multiple genders listed in dictionary

Tags: meaning, gender

The [Reverso dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/joghurt) lists `Joghurt` as either masculine or neuter. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Joghurt) lists it as masculine, feminine, or neuter.

Generally, is there a distinction between using the different genders in such cases? Is there a way to tell which gender is more commonly used?

Comment: related http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/for-new-words-which-are-often-nouns-who-sets-the-gender

Comment: It depends on the region. In standard German it's "der Jogurt"; don't care about the other variants. http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-jogurt-joghurt-a-311733.html

Comment: What "standard" German are you talking about, actually? It doesn't have to be listed by Duden to be legitimate, but it certainly is if it is, if you understand what I'm saying. Which is, by and large, that German is a pluricentric language, "standards" be damned. Der, die or das Jog(h)urt are all fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is there a distinction between using the different genders in such cases?

It depends. In case of Jogurt, there's no difference at all. It's the same thing. Dictionaries provide a single entry with all three genders. Wiktionary even adds some hints:

> In Deutschland ist der männliche Artikel am gebräuchlichsten; der sächliche ist eher selten. In der Schweiz und in Österreich wird der sächliche Artikel vornehmlich verwendet, wobei in Ostösterreich - und hier insbesondere der Gegend um Wien - auch noch selten umgangssprachlich der weibliche Artikel verwendet wird

Other words are different. Note, that a different gender is not the reason for a change in meaning. "Der Ball" has two meanings, although both are masculine (round object or dancing party).
Dictionaries provide separate entries if there are different 'versions' of that word. There are words in English, too. For instance, *lead* ([1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lead#lead), [2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lead#lead-2)).

- Is there a way to tell which gender is more commonly used?

Not exactly. Sometimes dictionaries adds some hints (see Jogurt above). If there's no hint, you can't tell.
Speaking of *Ball* (still no change in gender), you can bet that people usually talk of that round object rather than a dancing event.
Speaking of *See*, I'd guess that people usually mean a lake, but well, I go bathing in a lake quite regularly and travel once a year to the sea. Ask people who live at the sea and you may get a different opinion.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to tell for sure ... some few nouns as "See" do change meaning, but that would be mentioned in the dictionary anyway. You could do a research for regional accents, but if you can, go out and ask people directly. It's a mothertongue thing, and as far as I know, there is no standard rule to find out which one is Hochdeutsch. However, duden.de lists the most common usages, as for "Joghurt" http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Joghurt See "Grammatik" at the bottom of the page. (Which you probably already did. But you won't find much more information outside of linguistic papers ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certain nouns can be used with two or even all three genders;

> der/die/das Joghurt, der/das Teller, die/das Email usw.

Linguistically, they are not particularly interesting. Much more interesting are words that change their meaning, depending on the article used ...

> der Tor (fool) vs. das Tor (gate); der Band (volume) vs. das Band (ribbon) vs. die Band (band, as in musical group);  der/das Kiefer (jaw) vs. die Kiefer (pine); die
> Steuer (taxes) vs. das Steuer (rudder)

... or homonyms that have the same article in singular but a different one in plural:

> singular: die Bank, plural: 1. die Banken (financial institutions), 2. die Bänke (benches)
>
> singular: der Strauß, plural: 1. die Sträuße (bunches of flowers), 2. die Strauße (ostriches)

Answer (score 2):

Some words I know so far:

---

Das Plastik = the plastic (material)

Die Plastik = the sculpture

---

Die Leiter = the ladder

Der Leiter = head/manager/director/leader

Comment: Vielleicht magst Du ergänzen "Der Rosé (Wein), das Rosé (Farbe).

Answer (score 0):

"Anerkenntnis" is another case of two genders and usages. There seems to be no rule of thumb for distinctive meanings attributed to any gender here.

Comment: Not a good example. For one, "Anerkenntnis" is quite rare, usually in the sense of "Anerkennung" and then it's "die" at any rate. The second meaning of "Anerkenntnis" is a techical term (law), and it has a different meaning. "Jogurt" always is the same thing, unrelated to the preceding article.

Comment: Yes, this must be, without doubt, the single most important dual-gender noun.

Answer (score 0):

Der / die See have different meanings. Most nouns don't. The genders of those words varies regionally. It would be strange if you would mix usages of different regions.

Examples:

- der oder das Spital
- die oder das Cola
- der oder das Laptop
- der oder das Keks
- der oder das Prospekt
- der oder das Fakt
- der oder das Comic
- der oder das Gummi
- der oder das Puff
- der oder die Tsunami
- der oder die Salsa
- [...]

Answer (score -2):

In my humble opinion, *Joghurt* to be treated as an uncountable mass, like *Mus*. If referring to a serving of joghurt or particular kinds (as for *the sands*), you might use an article, and *der Joghurt* might well derive from *der Joghurt-Becher*, which is quite idiomatic, and ein Becher Joghurt*, equivalent to "Ich trinke ein (Glas) Wasser", though nobody eats a "Joghurt-Becher"; likewise *die Schale Joghurt* or *das Glas/Schälchen Joghurt*, or whatever else. The plural -s carries over, but sounds just a little weird, "Ich habe 5 Muse gegessen".

Indeed, *die* and *das Mus* both exist, but only *der Sand*. I'd speculate that age of the word plays a role, because many transgender words (what's the correct term again?) are borrowed (*apple sauce* vs *Apfelmus*, hence unlikely Germanic; ). Given enough time, a variant might win, and for diverging senses, separate genders might proliferate.

The uncountable distinction might not work for all words, and the substitution heuristic might not be all that is too it. Euphony could play a role, if vowelharmony differs across dialects.