# Artikel of "McDonald's"

Tags: article

I was thinking about how to ask a question like

> Wo ist der nächste McDonald's?

and I thought initially this was the correct way of going about it, but then I was left wondering what would the article of stores with real names e. g. McDonald's?

I don't know if the above article is correct, so it may be wrong.

**What is the article of specific popular stores in Deutsch (oder auf Deutsch)?**

Comment: The most agreeable solution if in doubt is to contract the article to d', "Sachma, wo's'n hier'd'nächste Mäckes"?

Comment: near duplicate of [words with multiple genders listed in dictionary](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15698/words-with-multiple-genders-listed-in-dictionary/49642)

Answer (score 2):

Store names are almost exclusively masculine.

> Wo ist der nächste Lidl?
>
> Wo ist der nächste McDonalds?

But pubs, hotels, ballrooms etc. are often neutral:

> Wo ist das nächste Fuller's?
>
> Wo ist das nächste Hilton?

Comment: For let's say a hotel this could be because it is "das Hotel" in german so it becomes "wo ist **das** nächste Hilton (**Hotel**)?". For stores I am not sure how this could be derived.

Comment: @puck, ich denke sofort an "der Laden"

Comment: @Iris: Der Laden (Markt), das Geschäft (Kaufhaus), die Lebensmittelhandlung (Zweigstelle, Niederlassung). Übersetzen hilft oft nicht weiter.

Comment: Can you source this claim? I beg to differ, concurring with @puck. There is no general rule, though a majority for masculine gendering might be appreciable, it's not overwhelming, and I would accept neuter inflection any day.

Comment: The question could be extended to generic terms like "der Computer", compared to the obsolete "das Computer", and further the question for nouns relating to females, because e.g. the profession of females is often given without female *-in* inflection, despite the political push for gendering--likewise for general nouns, *du alter Angeber*. I'm sure that has been discussed before, ad infinitum.

Comment: @vectory: *das Lidl*, *das Netto* or *das Burger King* sound wrong, to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not determined in any way and may differ dependent of whom you speak to. 
Example: There's a convenience Store called REWE. I say "der REWE", a friend of mine "die REWE" and another friend "das REWE". And that has nothing to do with the Region or regional language varieties.

Comment: I've never heard someone say "die" or "das" Rewe.

Comment: Interesting, on their website, I can't find an anwser to the right article, they only use combinations like "Ihrem REWE Markt" and "Ihrer REWE Filiale"

Comment: To me both sound wrong (die/das rewe). But I also say DER Blog instead of DAS Blog, because it sounds right to me...

Comment: Der REWE, as it is an acronym for "Revisionsverband der Westkauf-Genossenschaften" (der Verband), but correctly die EDEKA as this stands for "Einkaufsgenossenschaft der Kolonialwarenhändler" (die Genossenschaft)!

Comment: Yeah, sure, but you could use LIDL as a short form for DER LIDL-Laden. Which probably most People do in one form or another. there is probably a short form for every Genus, you can use the article whichever you want probably.

Answer (score 0):

When the gender of a proper name/company name isn't clear you usually complete it (in your mind) with a fitting term and use this terms gender ([see this thread](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25180/welches-pronomen-bei-firmennamen)).

For McDonald's there is no official article and therefore it's up to each person which one to use, as you can think of a McDonald's restaurant as e.g.

> Das McDonald's Restaurant
>
> Die McDonald's Filiale
>
> Der McDonald's Laden

McDonald's calls them McDonald's Restaurant, so "Das" is most likely, but "Der" seems to be more colloquial as in [another forum](https://raidrush.net/threads/der-oder-das-mcdonald.831819/) 60,8% said they use "Der" and 39,2% "Das". Maybe because McDonald's is seen a person or place.

Another example is "Der Aldi" as you can complete it as

> Der Aldi-Markt / Der Aldi-Discounter

Answer (score -1):

Just think about what it is:

"Wo ist *der* nächste Lidl?" - der Laden. This also applies to McDonalds.
Also most other other terms for shops are maskuline:
"der (Super)markt", "der Händler", "der Discounter", "der (Schreibwaren)Handel", additional to this in German exists the "Generische Maskulinum" which leads to most locations to be masculine, too. (Metzger, Bäcker, Krämer, etc...)
On pubs and restaurants it is most times das for "*das* Restaurant". It's different if the Restaurant has a classical "zum"-Name: zum Adler, zum Grünen Baum, zum Ochsen... in this case it's "der". This list goes on:
"wir gehen in das Hilton" - das Hotel
etc...

Comment: Der Laden, das Geschäft, die Einzelhandlung.

Comment: The use of articles is old. "Das Geschäft" and "Die Einzelhandlung" are rather new words in use. So yes, it's *der* from *der Laden*. If you go even firther back in language history you would find "der Krämer" which is also masculine. And to "das Hotel" would the older form be "das Gasthaus" though in this case it's "das Hotel" that's making the difference, as names are normally associated with the hotel-company

Comment: @userunknown reading the other answers and comments I think my point was confirmed. Nearly everyones first thought is "**der** Laden", so your word-collection is simply not applicable and feels forced.

Comment: Oder der Discounter, der Supermarkt, die Kaufhalle. Nearly everyone ist wer? 3 Hanseln im Internet, oder kennst Du eine qualifizierte Studie?

Comment: Oh good lord, cut the toxicity. The sheer consistency of shops being maskuline has obviosly a totally different reason, that you can define and verify? I don't know from which part in Germany you're come, but through all my my life shops were refferred to as *der* Laden, which always lead to the fact that when the name was used it still kept the *der*. My point stands, your examples feel forced.

Answer (score -1):

For these company names that come from English and end in an s, they are often mistaken for plurals as we treat companies as plural (*McDonalds **sell** hamburgers*) although they are singular when talking about the building (*Where **is** the next McDonalds*). However they are derived from genitive singulars e.g. *McDonald's restaurant* and McDonald's always spell (note my plural verb) it [this way](https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/about-us.html) so in German it is clearly short for *McDonalds Etwas* although I agree it is not clear what masculine word *Etwas* might be! Not sure if it helps but *McDonald* or *Mac Donald* is Scots Gaelic for *Donaldson* so is logically masculine.

Comment: The last line would be a worthy comment. The rest of the post is almost incomprehensible, because of multiple changes of opinion in the middle of the paragraph. If the corp. itself would refer to "das McDonalds Restaurant" and if you have not asserted that the name were most often dictating masculine inflection, then it's not clear why you would look for a masculine "*Etwas*".

Comment: Compare the bulk-seller "Metro". I would say either "die Metro", simply because the public transport "Metro" is also feminine. That's begging the question why that is female (n. in French and Slavic languages, f. in Italian; It. *metrum* "measure" is m., but n. in Latin; *Metropolis* is f., and rightly so as it derives from "mother", and even *polis* is f., as is Ger. *Stadt*), but the ugly truth is, that gender has to be learned, not inferred.

Comment: @David: "we treat companies as plural". AFAIK, Brits do treat companies and organizations as plural (e.g. "The police/Microsoft are searching for..."), but Americans don't ("The police/Microsoft is searching ...").

Comment: Aside from what has been said, I don’t see how a mistake speakers of English make is relevant to answer this question.

Comment: @vectory I'm not clear where I am contradicting myself. I'm saying that if we are going to use logic (and I know languages don't actually work like that!) then we find that *McDonalds* must originally have qualified some other noun, whose gender would be the logical one to use. The question starts with a masculine example, which is why I suggest that there must have been some masculine noun understood.

Comment: @vectory As for you comment about the Métro, this raises some interesting points. Metropolis means "mother city" so it is a type of city not a type of mother and takes is gender from *polis*. This word happens to be feminine, but there are several choices in Greek for city - *astu* is neuter. It could be that it is a "mother city" rather than a "father city" partly because *polis* is feminine.

Comment: @vectory But *Métro* does not come from *metropolis* but from the adjective *métropolitain* so we again have to ask what it qualifies. In French it [appears](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_du_m%C3%A9tro_de_Paris) to have been short for *réseau métropolitain* or *chemin de fer métropolitain* (both masculine) but in [Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitana) it appears to be short for *linea metropolitana* and so is feminine. I note, however, that that article also says "anche [...] la metro o il metrò"!