# »Der Joghurt« vs. »Das Joghurt«

Tags: etymology, gender

Wie ich bereits in einer anderen Frage erwähnt habe, lese ich gerade das Buch *Denksport Deutsch* von Daniel Scholten. Der erste Abschnitt, der rund 40 % des Buches ausmacht, ist dem unlogisch erscheinenden Genus-System der deutschen Sprache gewidmet. Scholten erklärt darin, wie in der protoindoeuropäischen Sprache (die er konsequent »Urindogermanisch« nennt) die drei Geschlechter entstanden sind, die sich heute in Deutsch und anderen daraus entstandenen Sprachen wiederfinden.

Zu dieser Hypothese habe ich eine Frage, doch dazu muss ich erst diese Hypothese zumindest in den wesentlichen Punkten wiedergeben:

---

### Die Hypothese

*(stark gekürzt, simplifiziert und ohne Erwähnung von Ausnahmen)*

Scholten springt von der Sprache der Hethiter zu Gotisch, Anatolisch, Vedisch, dann wieder zu Englisch, Latein, Altgriechisch und zwischendurch immer wieder zu Protoindoeuropäisch, und leitet dabei sehr plausibel her, dass das Geschlecht, das wir heute »männlich« nennen, die Urform aller Geschlechter ist.

Das heute »sächlich« genannte Geschlecht (obwohl »*die* Sache« selbst gar nicht sächlich ist) spaltete sich zuerst ab, nämlich als Bezeichnung von Tätigkeiten, oder als Bezeichnung für die Ergebnisse von Tätigkeiten (*das Pferdegeschirr* als Resultat von *anschirren*).

Eine besondere Pluralform, die man im Deutschen noch immer findet (Wörter-*Worte*, Männer-*Mann* (alle Mann an Bord), Länder-*Lande*), die aber mit einem Singular-Verb verwendet wurde (z.B. griechisch: πάντα ῥεῖ (*panta rhei*) = eigentlich *die Gesamten fließt*) war dann der Ursprung des Geschlechts, das heute *»weiblich«* genannt wird.

Das klingt alles sehr plausibel und glaubhaft. Insbesondere hat mich Scholten in einer in mir schon viel früher herangereiften Überzeugung bestärkt: Die Bezeichnungen »männlich«, »weiblich« und »sächlich« sind Unsinn und stiften nur Verwirrung weil sie falsche Annahmen implizieren.

So weit, so gut.

Scholten behauptet aber, dass derselbe Mechanismus, der vor mehreren Jahrtausenden die grammatischen Geschlechter entstehen ließ, noch heute unbewusst in unseren Köpfen wirkt, wenn wir Substantive aus fremden Sprachen ins Deutsche importieren. Er nennt dabei zwei Beispiele:

---

### Beispiel 1: Blog

Das Wort wurde im Englischen erfunden. Weil es keine Person und auch nichts personenartiges bezeichnet, wird im Englischen mit der sächlichen Präposition *it* darauf referenziert:

> Tom created a blog. I read **it**.

Das verleitete laut Scholten viele dazu, das vermeintlich sächliche Geschlecht auch in der deutschen Sprache zu verwenden: **das Blog**.

Das war aber seiner Meinung nach eine Kopfgeburt und im Grunde fehlerhaft, weil im Englischen nur Pronomen ein Geschlecht haben, Nomen aber nicht. Es kann im Englischen daher auch keine grammatische Kongruenz zwischen dem grammatischen Geschlecht eines Pronomens und dem eines Nomens geben. Aus der Tatsache, dass man im Englischen mit einem Pronomen eines bestimmten Geschlechts auf ein bestimmtes Nomen verweist, kann man keinen Schluss auf das grammatische Geschlecht des Nomens ziehen.

Der in unseren Sprachzentren verortete Mechanismus, der abseits der bewussten Wahrnehmung arbeitet, fragt laut Scholten, ob man dem Wort an sich irgend eine Bedeutung ansehen kann, oder auch ob es den Anschein erweckt, von etwas bereits bekannten abgeleitet zu sein.

Im Fall von **the meeting** erkennt das Sprechzentrum: *»Das ist von einer Tätigkeit, nämlich von* sich treffen *abgeleitet, und als Tätigkeitsbezeichnung daher sächlich.«* Und so ist dieses Substantiv im Deutschen auch tatsächlich sächlich: **das Meeting.**

Im Fall von **the blog** findet das Sprachzentrum aber keinen Hinweis auf irgend eine Bedeutung, die sich direkt aus dem Wort allein ableiten lässt. Es kann nicht als Tätigkeitsbezeichnung und nicht als Abstraktion von irgend etwas anderem identifiziert werden. Daher gilt der Default-Fall, und das heißt: *männlich*. Also **der Blog**.

Aus diesem Grund (*fehlerhafte Herleitung aus dem Englischen* vs. *unbewusster Mechanismus des Sprachzentrums*) wird *Blog* heute beiden Geschlechtern zugeordnet:

> das Blog
>   der Blog

---

### Beispiel 2: Joghurt

Scholten führt das Wort *»Joghurt«* als weiteres Beispiel an. Die türkische Sprache kennt keine grammatischen Geschlechter, und als das türkische Wort *yoğurt* seinen Weg in den deutschen Wortschatz antrat, gab es absolut keine Anhaltspunkte für ein grammatisches Geschlecht. Der von Scholten postulierte Mechanismus klopft das Wort ab, findet nichts woraus sich andere Geschlechter ergeben könnten, und spuckt den Defaultwert »männlich« aus:

> der Joghurt.

Für einen *Piefke* durchaus plausibel. Das Problem ist aber: Die *Ösis* (und möglicherweise auch Bayern, dazu kann ich leider nichts sagen) sagen aber trotzdem:

> das Joghurt.

Während einige Wörter zumindest in Österreich sowohl männlich als auch sächlich sein können (der/das Radio) gehört *Joghurt* zu den Wörtern, die in Österreich ausschließlich sächlich sind. Die männliche Variante wird in Österreich als falsch empfunden. Ein anderes Wort, auf das dasselbe zutrifft, ist:

> das Keks.

(importiert aus dem englischen Plural von *cake*: *cakes*)

**Anekdote:**
<sub>Der deutsche Joghurt-Hersteller Danone hat vor einiger Zeit eine Fernsehwerbung für sein Produkt *Activia* ausgestrahlt, in der folgende Handlung gezeigt wurde:</sub>
<sub>Vor einem Kühlregal mit Activia-Joghurt steht ein attraktiver junger Mann. Etwas entfernt davon stehen zwei junge Frauen und schauen zu dem Mann vor dem Jughurtregal. Eine der beiden Frauen sagt dann: »**Den** hole ich mir jetzt«, geht auf den Mann zu, an ihm vorbei und nimmt ein Joghurt aus dem Regal.</sub>
<sub>Dieser Werbespot spielt mit der Attraktivität des Mannes und des Joghurts, funktioniert aber nur, wenn *Joghurt* tatsächlich männlich ist. In Österreich hat dieser Werbespot nicht funktioniert. Er rief nur verständnisloses Kopfschütteln hervor.</sub>
<sub>Wie der Spot auf Österreicher gewirkt hat, kann man nachvollziehen, indem man Joghurt durch Eis (Speiseeis) ersetzt: Die Frau sagt: »**Den** hole ich mir jetzt«, geht auf den Mann zu, an ihm vorbei und nimmt ein Eis aus dem Regal.</sub>
<sub>Als Danone auf den Fehler aufmerksam gemacht wurde, hat man aus dem Spot den erwähnten Satz herausgeschnitten, was den Spot aber gänzlich unbrauchbar gemacht hat. Dann wurde er (zumindest in Österreich) ganz abgesetzt.</sub>

---

### Was ich nun wissen möchte:

Sind die österreichischen sächlichen Version von *Joghurt* und *Keks* Beweise dafür, dass sich Scholten nicht nur bei einem einzelnen Wort (*der/das Joghurt*) irrt, sondern dass er ganz grundsätzlich falsch liegt?

Falls die Hypothese grundsätzlich und im Großen und Ganzen korrekt ist: Was könnte die Ursache dafür sein, dass *Joghurt* und *Keks* in Österreich (und möglicherweise auch in Bayern) sächlich sind, während beide Wörter nördlich davon männlich sind?

Und dann würde ich gerne wissen, warum das bei den Wörtern *Gummi* und *Schlüsselbund* genau umgekehrt ist:

> In Österreich: der Gummi, der Schlüsselbund
>   In Deutschland: das Gummi, das Schlüsselbund

(Ob Bayern sich in dieser Sache österreichisch oder deutsch verhält, weiß ich nicht)

(Zu *Schlüsselbund*: Ich ging bis gestern davon aus, dass dieses Wort auch in Deutschland männlich ist. Aber in Scholtens Buch kommt auch dieses Wort vor, und wird dort - sehr zu meinem Befremden - ganz selbstverständlich als sächliches Wort verwendet: »Der Lehrer warf dem Schüler *das* Schlüsselbund an den Kopf«)

---

Nachtrag (Reaktion auf Kommentare):

zu **Bund**:

In Österreich ist **der Bund** eine ganz offizielle Bezeichnung für die Vereinigung der neun Bundesländer. Es gibt z.B. Straßen, die von jeweils einem Land erhalten werden (die Landesstraßen) und Straßen, für deren Erhaltung *der* Bund sorgt (Bundesstraßen).

Auch der obere Abschluss einer Hose ist männlich: *Der* Hosenbund.

Es gibt aber auch in Österreich *das* Bund Petersilie.

Daher habe ich eben nicht einfach nur *Bund*, sondern ausdrücklich *Schlüsselbund* geschrieben. Der ist in Österreich nämlich ganz klar männlich: *Der* Schlüsselbund.

zu **Gummi**:

Das Synonym für das Kondom ist (zumindest in Österreich) ebenso männlich wie das dehnbare Band im Hosenbund, das die Hose am Körper hält: Der Gummi. Auch der Radiergummi ist genau so männlich und der Gummi aus dem Reifen bestehen.

Comment: Ohne Relevanz für die Frage: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bund_Gebundenes

Comment: *Das Gummi* bezeichnet zumindest in Norddeutschland das Material Gummi, während *der Gummi* ein Bauteil aus Gummi ist.

Comment: Hilfreich für die Beantwortung dieser Frage wäre sicherlich ein Vergleich mit anderen indogermanischen Sprachen. Ich denke vor allem ans Französische, weil es dort kein Neutrum gibt.

Comment: Darüber hinaus: Auch "setting" ist im Deutschen sächlich, obwohl es mit keiner Tätigkeit verbunden ist. Ich vermute eher, dass die Wortendung "-ing" für die Assoziation mit dem sächlichen Genus verantwortlich ist.

Comment: Ich lebe in Bayerisch-Schwaben, kenne *der* und *das* Joghurt, war mir aber nie so sicher, was davon hochdeutsch ist und was Dialekt. *das* Schlüsselbund kenne ich nicht, nur *der* Schlüsselbund. *der* Gummi ist ein Teil oder Ding aus Gummi, *das* Gummi ist das Material. *der* Teller ist hochdeutsch, *das* Teller sagen wir im Dialekt, *der* Butter ist Dialekt, *die* Butter ist hochdeutsch, *der* und *das* Radio gehen in meinem Umfeld durcheinander ... ich kann kein Muster erkennen ... evtl. müsste man mal eine annähernd vollständig Liste solcher Wörter erstellen.

Comment: Nicht der Grund, nur die Karte: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f24a-g/

Comment: Ich erinnere mich noch als ich das Wort das erste mal aktive nutzen wollte hatte ich Probleme den Artikel aus dem Wort intuitiv abzuleiten. Das war zu einem Zeitpunkt zu dem noch kaum jemand hier in Deutschland wusste was das ist, ein Blog. Ich entschied mich dafür das der Blog richtig ist nachdem ich die genaue Bedeutung recherchierte. Weblog - Web Protokoll. Das Protokoll. Auch mein erster EInfall für eine deutsche Übersetzung war Tagebuch - das Tagebuch. Ich glaube das der verwendete Artikel "der" für Blog meistens so hergeleitet worde bevor es Wörterbücher und Medien es weitläufig nutzten.

Comment: Weiteres Paar, wenn 's denn hilft: Der Teil (pars) und das Teil (umgangssprachlich für "Ding")

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/for-new-words-which-are-often-nouns-who-sets-the-gender

Comment: *Das E-mail* oder *die E-mail*? - Nach Scholtens Logik (die ich grundsätzlich überzeugend finde) läge es dem deutschen Steinzeithirn nahe, *der E-mail* zu sagen. Noch dazu, also auch *der Brief* ja "männlich* artikuliert wird. Aber hier ist wohl die Bedeutung von *mail* als *Post* (und damit *die*) zu stark...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Stimmt. Nach Scholten müsste es *der E-Mail* heißen. Auf jeden Fall aber mit großem M. (In Ö übrigens vorwiegend *das E-Mail*)

Comment: Für mich (Niedersachse) heißt es "die Joghurt". Mit männlichem Artikel wirkt es auf mich sehr befremdlich.

Comment: Aus Moselfranken stammend ist es für mich der Radiergummi und der Schlüsselbund. Das Bund Petersilie habe ich aber schon oft gehört. Ich schätze aber, dass ich meistens "der Bund" sage. Ein guter Freund ist aber Österreicher - das färbt mit der Zeit ab.

Comment: Ich habe Scholten so verstanden, dass sich das Geschlecht durchsetzt, das dem intuitiven Sprechen am nächsten kommt. Der Durchschnittskunde sieht im Laden einen Joghurt, aber ohne Artikel, und muss sich entscheiden ohne zu forschen, ob das Wort aus dem türkischen kommt (ich dachte: Bulgarien) und welches Geschlecht es da hat. Die Entscheidung wird dann laienhaft mit Begründungen unterfüttert. Da ich ein wenig Französisch gelernt habe habe ich auch gelernt, dass das Geschlecht oft nicht übereinstimmt und keineswegs nur bei Wörtern, die im dt. sächlich sind.

Comment: Welche besonderen Einflüsse in Bayern und Österreich zu falschen :) Artikeln geführt haben interessiert mich aber auch.

Comment: @userunknown: Danke für den Smiley hinter *»falschen«*. Denn weder die deutschländischen noch die österreichischen sind falsch. Sie sind zwar unterschiedlich, aber beide sind völlig korrekt.

Comment: Einem Land, dem wir Thomas Bernhard und Karl Kraus verdanken, kann man sprachliche Kompetenz schlecht pauschal absprechen. Oder Josef Hader (oder war das jetzt Haderer? Ne, das ist der Zeichner, aber auch leiwand).

Comment: @userunknown: Trotzdem ist es leider noch immer so, das viele Leute das österreichische Deutsch als zweitrangig ansehen, verglichen mit dem deutschen Deutsch. Das ist auch in Österreich so: Viele Österreicher glauben, das deutsche Deutsch sei der eigenen Muttersprache irgendwie vorzuziehen. Viele halten das österreichische Deutsch für eine schlampige Version von "Hochdeutsch", oder halten es gar für einen Dialekt. Aber beides ist falsch. Es steht qualitativ gleichrangig neben den beiden anderen Standardvarietäten. Es unterscheidet sich lediglich in der Zahl der Sprecher.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn du Österreicher suchst, die mit Sprache gut umgehen können, dann suche auf Youtube nach »Gunkl« (alias Günther Paal). Ich habe leider keine Ahnung wie gut man ihn in Deutschland kennt. Er tritt immer auf einer völlig leeren Bühne auf, und bewegt sich den ganzen Abend keinen Millimeter (außer um ab- und abzutreten). Aber was da an Sprache aus ihm heraus kommt, ist atemberaubend. Und es erfordert große Aufmerksamkeit vom Publikum. Gunkl kann man nicht "so nebenbei" anhören. Auf seiner Homepage kann man auch seine alten Programme nachlesen: http://gunkl.at

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Kenn ich. Der war ständiger Gast in Dorfers Donnerstalk auf 3sat, eben hatte ich den Namen noch. Saß da aber meiner Erinnerung nach im abgedunkelten Hinten an einem Tisch und war der Experte für eh Alles. Die Sendung war aber selbst bei Leuten, die sonst alles komische von Heute-Show bis DieAnstalt über Extra3 und was weiß ich gesehen haben wenig bekannt - wohl wg. des Senders. Ich glaube die Deutschen zeigen einen ähnlichen Minderwertigkeitskomplex bezogen auf die Amerikaner.

Answer (score 6):

> Sind die österreichischen sächlichen Version von Joghurt und Keks Beweise dafür, dass sich Scholten nicht nur bei einem einzelnen Wort irrt ...

Für die Hypothese, dass die Genera ursprünglich so verteilt wurden: Natürlich nicht. Die entsprechenden Wörter hat es damals noch nicht gegeben.

> Scholten behauptet aber, dass derselbe Mechanismus, ... **noch heute** unbewusst in unseren Köpfen wirkt ...

Ja und nein - aber eher nein:

Die Frage, auf die hier schon öfters eingegangen wurde, ist diejenige, wie denn neue Wörter im Deutschen ein Genus bekommen.

Laut Internet orientieren sich Sprecher an folgenden Kriterien, bevor es eine "offizielle" Regelung für ein Wort gibt:

- Genus in der Herkunftssprache (falls diese Genera kennt)
- Bekannte Wörter mit ähnlicher Bedeutung
- Klang des Wortes / Wortendung

Sollte das Genus aus der Herkunftssprache übernommen werden und die Sprache mit Deutsch verwandt ist, sind die Genera in der Ursprungssprache bereits auf die von Scholten beschriebene Art und Weise gebildet worden. So gesehen hat die damalige Denkweise der Menschen Einfluss auf die Genera der Fremdwörter heute.

Was die Vergabe des Genus nach bekannten Wörtern mit ähnlicher Bedeutung (und wohl auch nach der Wortendung) angeht, sieht es ähnlich aus: Damals hat ein Wort ein Genus bekommen und heute wird das Genus für ein anderes Wort übernommen.

Die Denkweise der Menschen von damals ist sozusagen in den bereits bekannten Wörtern "gespeichert" und wird heute auf die neuen Wörter übertragen. Aber eben nicht deswegen, weil die Leute heute noch genau so denken, sondern deswegen, weil sie die Genera von bekannten Wörtern auf neue Wörter übertragen.

Die Tatsache, dass die meisten englischsprachigen Fremdwörter im Deutschen zunächst mit unterschiedlichen Genera verwendet wurden, spricht für mich dagegen, dass eine von existierenden Wörtern "unabhängige" Denkweise noch existiert.

Answer (score 6):

Ich habe das Buch nicht gelesen, kann daher nur mit dem argumentieren, was Hubert daraus zitiert - An einen "tief eingepfanzten, unbewussten" Mechanismus zur Genusbildung glaube ich nicht (ganz). Dafür gibt es in den Sprachen, die alle protoindoeuropäische Wurzeln haben, viel zu viele überraschende Unterschiede (z.B. deutsch - französisch). Die Erklärung ist mir viel zu einfach und Sprache ist nicht so "straightforward".  Möglicherweise gibt es so einen Mechanismus sogar, aber er ist nur einer von sehr, sehr vielen, und bei weitem nicht der wichtigste.

Schaut man einem Kind beim Spracherwerb zu, stellt man fest, dass Genus etwas ist, das ein Kind erstmal überhaupt nicht braucht, um zu sprechen, sondern die ersten Berührungen damit ergeben sich durch Lernen - Da ist nix "angeboren" oder "in die Sprache implantiert".

Die allermeisten Genusbildungen funktionieren m.A. nach **heute** durch eine Art Lautmustererkennung und haben mit der *Bedeutung* eines Wortes erstmal gar nichts zu tun, sondern nur mit der Auslautung und u.U. der Silbenanzahl und -betonung des Wortes - Beispiel: Substantive auf "-ie", die aus fremden Sprachen kommen (die Herkunftssprache selbst ist dabei ziemlich egal), sind **feminin**. (*Menagerie*, *Analogie*, *Prärie*, sogar *Arie*). Würde es "Blogie" heißen, könnten wir mit ziemlicher Sicherheit davon ausgehen, dass der/das Blog feminin geworden wäre.
Anderes Beispiel: Substantive mit "-ing" am Ende, werden größtenteils Neutren im Deutschen, welche mit "-a" aus romanischen Sprachen größtenteils feminin.

Mit einem "protoindoeuropäisch verankerten Mechanismus" hat das aber meiner Meinung nach überhaupt nichts zu tun - wir nehmen einfach unbewußt die Gesamtheit unseres Wortschatzes her und bilden das Geschlecht aus diesem Wissen - Dass da viel "protoindoeuropäisches" drinsteckt, mag schon stimmen, trotzdem ist man sich absolut einig, das es z.B "das Sushi" und "die Sisha" heißen muss. Unsere Sprache hat das protoindoeuropäische eben schon viel zu lange hinter sich.

Der Erklärung, dass die Genuswahl etwas mit der *Bedeutung* eines Wortes zu tun haben könnte, steht auch entgegen, dass es viel zu viele Synonyme gibt, die denselben Begriff addressieren, aber unterschiedliches Genus haben:

Boot - Kahn - Nachen - Schaluppe - Schiff - Dampfer - ...

Zumindestens die ersten drei sind absolut bedeutungsgleich und haben unterschiedliche grammatische Geschlechter. Die anderen sind zumindestens ähnlich. Wir werden uns aber wahrscheinlich sofort einig sein, das ein Wort, das mit "-er" aufhört, mit großer Wahrscheinlichkeit maskulin sein muss, eins mit "-ahn" ebenfalls, solange wir keinen detaillierteren Grund für was anderes finden.

"Joghurt" und "Blog" sind schöne Beispiele, wo diese Mustererkennung uns nicht weiterbringt (weil es keine "vergleichbaren" Lautungen in unsrer bekannten Sprache gibt), und schon ist der Mechanismus ratlos und führt regional zu unterschiedlichen Ergebnissen - Wir werden uns nicht einig - Worin wir uns aber wahrscheinlich sofort einig sind, ist, das beide **nicht** feminin sein können. Daraus folgere ich, dass man mit Vorliebe maskulin oder neutrum annimmt, wenn nichts spezifisch für feminin spricht. 
Hätte die *Bedeutung* irgendeinen Einfluß auf das Genus, müsste man sich beim Joghurt wohl an der "Dickmilch" orientieren - Hat man aber nicht.

Für mich ist die Auslautung im Zusammenspiel mit der Silbenanzahl und -betonung der wichtigste Wegweiser für die Genusbildung (der natürlich Ausnahmen kennt, sonst wäre es kein Deutsch...). Danach kommen viele verschiedene untergeordnete Regeln, von denen es viel zu viele gibt, um sie hier aufzuzählen. Intellektuelle Kapazität wird allerdings erst investiert, wenn die Regeln der Auslautung und Lautähnlichkeit nicht zu einem annehmbaren Ziel führen. Greift gar nichts mehr, überlassen wir es vielleicht sogar dem Zufall.

Fazit: Ein Geflecht massiv vieler verschiedener hierarchischer "Regeln", nach denen wir das Genus annehmen - Die Auslautung m.A. nach mit großem Abstand die wichtigste, danach kommen Wortherkunft (Germanischer oder romanischer Sprachraum oder "woanders"), erst danach (vielleicht) Bedeutung. Dass den Mustern, nach denen wir heute hauptsächlich die Genusbildung vornehmen, ursprünglich eine protoindogermanische Wurzel zugrunde lag, mag ja sein - Allerdings hat die Sprache in der langen Zeit bis heute so viele Wendungen genommen und neue Einflüsse absorbiert, dass davon kaum noch etwas übrig sein dürfte.

Noch ein schönes Beispiel ist die Vornamenwahl - Selbst wenn wir unsere Kinder "Cheyenne", "November" oder "Tiger" oder mit anderen, vollkommen ungebräuchlichen Namen belegen, können wir bis auf wenige Ausnahmen sofort sagen "das ist aber kein Mädchen-/Jungenname!" - und auch das hat seine Herkunft sicher in Auslautung und Betonung. Mit diesem Thema beschäftigen sich sogar Gerichte und die kommen meist auch zu einem vernünftigen Urteil darüber.

Comment: Die Antwort ist lang, aber sie geht nicht richtig auf die ursprüngliche Frage ein. Dort geht es in erster Linie um Wörter wie *Joghurt* oder *Blog,* wo man nichts findet, «woraus sich andere Geschlechter ergeben könnten». Also eben gerade keine typischen Endungen. Wie nun aber bei solchen Wörtern die Genus-Zuteilung funktioniert, bleibt bei dieser Antwort unklar.

Comment: @mach: Ich finde schon, dass diese Antwort die ursprüngliche Frage richtig aufgreift und beantwortet, indem sie darlegt, dass es keine grundsätzlichen Regeln gibt, nach denen das Genus eines "neuen" Wortes festgelegt wird. Die Frage, ob *Joghurt* und *Keks* Scholtens Hypothese belegen können, ist für mich dadurch negativ beantwortet. Auf den/das *Bund* lässt sich das ebenfalls übertragen ... Vorausgesetzt natürlich, tofros Hypothesen treffen zu (für mich klingen sie plausibel).

Comment: @mach Ich bin überzeugt, dass die Genuszuteilung relativ willkürlich **ist**, wenn unsre Sprachgeschichte uns keinen "Leitfaden" dazu zur Seite stellen *kann*. *Femininum oder nicht* ist noch relativ klar (nur wenige "vollkommen neue" Wörter bekommen das). Neutrum oder Maskulinum ist viel schwieriger und, glaube ich, auch viel zufälliger. Versuch' dir mal, irgendein Fantasie-Substantiv auszudenken und überlege dir, ob es "der", "die" oder "das" heißen muß. Du wirst merken, dass du sofort eine Meinung dazu haben wirst ob (f) oder nicht. (n) und (m) brauchen normalerweise ein bisschen länger.

Comment: @mach Eine *richtige* Antwort müsste, glaube ich, noch viel länger sein. Das Thema ist so komplex, dass man darüber ein Buch schreiben könnte...

Comment: Gute Antwort, danke (+1), aber trotzdem Kritik: Ich stimme überhaupt nicht darin überein, dass »Sisha« weiblich sein sollte. Aus dem Bauch heraus hätte ich »das Sisha« gesagt. (Falls damit die orientalische Wasserpfeife gemeint ist: Die ist tatsächlich weiblich, schreibt sich aber *Shisha* oder *Schischa*). Aber in Österreich sind aber auch *das Cola* und *das Fanta* sächlich, obwohl beide auf *-a* enden. Übrigens gibt es auch nicht wenige Männer, die *Maria* (meist als 2. Vorname) oder *Andrea* (viele Italiener) heißen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Die Regeln, die ich genannt habe, haben (selbstverständlich) massenhaft Ausnahmen.  Und natürlich ist das Muster, nachdem wir ein Genus annehmen, regional und sogar individuell verschieden. Sonst hättest du deine Frage ja gar nicht stellen müssen.

Comment: Du meinst wohl, dass fast alle Wörter auf "-ing" männlich sind, nicht sächlich: Der Zwilling, der Flüchtling, der Schönling, der Rörhling, der Mischling, der Feigling, der Bratling, der Hering, Wüstling, Pudding, Ring, - gibt es überhaupt ein sächliches? Für ~er gibt es zu viele und zu gebräuchliche, um von Ausnahmen zu sprechen: Die Mutter, die Tochter, die Butter, das Messer, … . Zu ~ahn: Die Bahn, die Lahn.

Comment: Bei Personennamen muss ich auch widersprechen. An den Wörtern und wie sie klingen kann ich nicht festmachen, ob "Cheyenne, Tiger oder November" Mädchen- oder Jungsnamen sind. Das kann man ja bei gebräuchlichen, ausländischen Namen schon oft nicht (siehe Andrea, Alexander, Joan, ...). Bei Wörtern auf ~ie, wie Monarchie, Hysterie, Orthographie, Ideologie handelt es sich sehr oft um Abstrakta. Wie auch bei ~keit (Männlichkeit, Festigkeit, Kleinigkeit) und die sind fast immer weiblich.

Answer (score 2):

Die These, dass bei der Zuordnung eines Genus für Fremdwörter wie *Blog* oder *Joghurt,* die nicht offensichtlich mit einem bestimmten Genus assoziiert sind (z.B. über eine typische Endung), noch immer die ursprüngliche indogermanische Genus-Verteilung wirkt, dünkt mich sehr unwahrscheinlich. Bei den deutschen Substantiven hat sich die Genus-Verteilung über die Jahrtausende derart von der ursprünglichen grammatischen Logik entfernt, dass es keine Regel mehr gibt. Das können alle bestätigen, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen oder lehren.

Die übliche Erklärung ist die, dass sich das Genus für derartige Fremdwörter nach einheimischen Wörtern mit ähnlicher Bedeutung richtet. Dabei gibt es oft unterschiedliche Möglichkeiten: *das Blog* neutrum wie *das (Log-)Buch* oder maskulinum wie *der Brief* usw.

Comment: Ich bezweifel sehr das viele Menschen Blogs in der Bedeutung ähnlich zu Briefen sehen. Protokoll(buch) oder Tagebuch scheint mir um einiges nähr. Es ist klar das dies nur ein Beispiel ist, dennoch.

Comment: Die These ist, wenn ich es recht verstehe, ja nicht so sehr, dass diese ursprüngliche Form der Genus-Zuteilung bei den Leuten, die vor sagen wir 5000 Jahren etwas sprachen, was wir heute Urindogermanisch o.ä. nennen, noch heute wirkt. Sondern vielmehr ist es einfach eine Erklärung, wo das, was wir heute "Geschlecht" oder "Genus" eines Substantivs nennen, vielleicht herkommt.