# Heiraten und Raten

Tags: etymology

Entschuldigung, ich bin Amerikaner, lebe in NYC und verwende Deutsch nicht so oft. Also mein Deutsch... könnte besser sein.

Ich denke an das Wort "Heiraten", besonders dass am Ende "raten" ist. Auf Englisch gibt es einen alten Ausdruck (jetzt nicht mehr üblich): "She is spoken for", was "sie ist verheiratet oder verlobt" bedeutet. Ist das dasselbe oder ähnlich wie "raten" in Heiraten?

(Und ich wundere mich, ob Heiraten vs. "Hai"raten manchmal ein Spiel in Deutschland ist.)

Comment: "Raten" bedeutet auf Englisch "to guess" oder "to advise". Es hat nicht das Geringste zu tun mit Heirat oder Verlobung.

Comment: Das würde ich so nicht sagen: https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Heirat

Comment: *Und ich wundere mich, ob Heiraten vs. "Hai"raten manchmal ein Spiel in Deutschland ist.* – Alice: »Hammerhai« – Bert: »Nein.« – Alice: »Weißer  Hai« – Bert: »Nein.« – Alice: »Walhai« – Bert: »Nein.« – Alice: »Katzenhai« – Bert: »Nein.« – Caroline: »Was macht ihr gerade?« – Alice und Bert: »Hai raten!«. — Geht auch mit »π raten«.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Komm, nachher heißts noch, der π-Zar hätte was mit italienischen Speisen zu tun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### heiraten, die Heirat

Das deutsche Verb *»heiraten«* ist eine Ableitung aus dem Substantiv *»Heirat«* (Vermählung, Eheschließung). Die Heirat ist also der Zeitpunkt an dem zwei Personen, die bisher ledig (oder geschieden) waren, zu Eheleuten werden. Und auch das Verb *»heiraten«* beschreibt diesen einmaligen und kurzen Vorgang. Ein Synonym für *»Heirat«* ist *»Hochzeit«.* Auch dieses Wort beschreibt denselben kurzen Zeitpunkt.

Davon zu unterscheiden ist die *»Ehe«.* Dieses Wort beschriebt den Zustand des offiziellen Zusammengehörens, der nach der Heirat bis zum Tod eines der beiden Eheleute oder bis zur Scheidung andauert.

#### Heirat = Heim + Rat

Das Wort *»Heirat«* gilt im modernen Deutsch nicht mehr als Kompositum, aber aufgrund seiner Entstehung ist es das eigentlich doch. Das Wort *»Heirat«* war mittelhochdeutsch *»hīrāt«* (die Querstriche über den Vokalen zeigen an, dass sie lang ausgesprochen wurden) und bestand althochdeutsch aus diesen beiden Teilen:

- hīwo, hīo (masc.) bzw. hīwa, hīa (fem.)
  Hausgenosse (-genossin), Gatte, Gattin, Dienstbote, Familenangehörige(r), usw.
- rāt (masc.)
  alles, was für Ernährung und Erhaltung eines Haushalts erforderlich ist (vergleiche: Hausrat, Vorrat, Gerät, Unrat)

Das Wort hīwo (hīo, hīwa, hīa) ist etymologisch wiederum eng mit *»Heim«* (Wohnsitz, Wohnung Heimat, Haus, Dorf, Versammlungsort) verwandt.

Die *»Heirat«* ist also der Akt der Gründung einer Lebensgemeinschaft und eines gemeinsamen Haushalts.

Auf die Frage warum *die Heirat (fem.)* ein anderes grammatikalisches Geschlecht als *der Rat (masc.)* hat, weiß ich leider keine Antwort. Aber dass es so ist, belegt, dass die *Heirat* schon seit sehr langer Zeit (vermutlich seit mehreren Jahrhunderten) nicht mehr als Kompositum sondern als eigenständiges Wort wahrgenommen wird. Denn bevor ein Kompositum unabhängig von seinem letzten Bestandteil das Geschlecht ändern kann, muss das Wort in der Wahrnehmung der Sprechen den Status eines Kompositums verlieren.

#### Rat, raten

Das Wort *»rāt«* hat daneben noch eine Reihe anderer Bedeutungen: *beschließendes Gremium, Überlegung, Vorschlag, Entschluss, Empfehlung, Vorsorge* und in früheren Zeiten auch noch *die Beschaffung von Mitteln und Vorräten*

Damit einher gehen auch mehrere Bedeutungen des Verbs *»raten«:*

1. Eine Empfehlung abgeben

> Ich **rate** dir, zum Arzt zu gehen
> 2. Eine Vermutung anstellen
> **Rate** mal, was mein Chef heute zu mir gesagt hat.

In früheren Zeiten wurde das Verb auch für *Vorsoge treffen* verwendet. Das ist zwar die Bedeutung von *»rat«* in *»Heirat«,* aber wird heute nicht mehr mit dem Verb *»raten«* assoziiert.

---

#### Hai raten

Ja, dieses Wortspiel gibt es im Deutschen. Als meine Frau und ich geheiratet haben, haben wir bei der Hochzeitsfeier einen Geschenk bekommen. Wir mussten vorher raten, was es war. Es war ein aufblasbarer Hai.

Comment: Besteht Ihres Wissens irgendwelcher Grund, warum "Heirat" feminin ist, im Gegensatz zu "Rat" & "Hausrat" & "Vorrat" & "Unrat", die alle maskulin sind?

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI, gewiss unter Einfluss der mehr abstrakten Bedeutung ;) https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=H05592

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI: Danke für die Frage, ich habe dazu einen Absatz oberhalb der Überschrift *»Rat, raten«* eingefügt. Dass Wörter im Lauf er Zeit ihr Geschlecht ändern, kommt häufiger vor als viele vermuten. Das ist auch der Grund, warum es so viele Substantive gibt, die zwar zweifelsfrei dasselbe Wort sind, aber in unterschiedlichen geographischen Regionen unterschiedliche Geschlechter haben. Siehe dazu auch [diese Liste](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/49434/1487) und [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/37860/1487)