# Was ist das Genus von Skyr?

Tags: noun, gender

Wikipedia beschreibt [Skyr](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyr) wie folgt

> **Skyr** (...) ist ein traditionelles isländisches Milchprodukt und ist mit Quark oder dickflüssigem Joghurt zu vergleichen; bestimmte Bakterienkulturen spielen ähnlich dem Joghurt eine Rolle bei dessen Herstellung.

Zur Herstellung schreibt Wikipedia (Hervorhebung von mir):

> Zuerst wird die Milch pasteurisiert (auf etwa 72 bis 75 °C erhitzt), um Bakterien abzutöten, anschließend wird die Milch auf 38 °C abgekühlt **mit etwas fertigem Skyr** geimpft sowie ursprünglich mit Lab.

Ich gehe also davon aus, dass das Nomen Skyr entweder ein Maskulinum oder ein Neutrum ist. Oder hat man die Wahl? Im [Online Duden](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Skyr) habe ich das Wort nicht gefunden. (Ohne Genus kein Genuss.)

Comment: Related (auf englisch): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/for-new-words-which-are-often-nouns-who-sets-the-gender

Comment: Das darfst du dir (noch) selbst aussuchen. Solange sich genug Leute finden, die deiner Auffassung folgen, kannst du damit sogar die deutsche Sprache formen.

Answer (score 9):

Das Wort kommt aus einer anderen Sprache. Deshalb gibt es zunächst keinen vorgeschriebenen Artikel.
Es gibt wohl bestimmte Grundsätze bei der Einbürgerung eines Wortes. So ist der Feta wohl maskulin, weil der Käse es auch ist. Das gilt wohl auch für das Ale und das Bier. Beim Zaziki andererseits nennt selbst der Dunden Maskulinum und Neutrum, genauso wie beim Hummus.
Die Pizza könnte sich wiederum aus der Endung des Wortes mit **a** ergeben, genau wie die Pasta oder Sangria.

Es gibt also kein eindeutiges Kriterium welches Genus verwendet werden muss und es daher wohl eine Frage was sich letztlich durchsetzt. Da **Joghurt** laut der Online-Version des Duden alle 3 Möglichkeiten erlaubt, gibt es von dieser Richtung auch keine klare Ansage, obwohl **der** wohl am gebräuchlichsten ist.

In Bezug auf Skyr halte ich **die** für am unwahrscheinlichsten. Vom Klang her würde auch **der** ganz gut passen.
Aus meinem Sprachempfinden  heraus würde ich erst mal **das** verwenden, weil das irgendwie die erste Lösung für eine verformbare homogene Masse ist. Allerdings komme ich aus einer Gegend wo man auch "**der Butter**" sagt.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich gibt es kein Kriterium, um ein Genus für *Skyr* bewusst zu wählen; die Tatsache ist, dass Muttersprachler *Skyr* verwendet (und gar essen) ohne unbedingt sich einig sein zu müssen. Was geschrieben ist kann man aber gewissermaßen beobachten. Das Genus von Skyr (als Funktion des Orts) ist m.E. die Antwort. Die gibt es aber wohl nicht. :)

Comment: Leider (oder zum Glück?) ist es eher so, dass die Sprache erstmal irgendein (normalerweise nicht feminin) Genus für ein fremdes Nomen annimmt und hinterher einen guten Grund dafür findet statt andersrum.

Comment: @tofro Dass ein zufälliges Genus gewählt wird halte ich eher für die Ausnahme. Da wird im Gehirn eine entsprechende Genusanfrage an die verantwortliche Stelle geschickt und aufgrund der sprachlichen Erfahrungen der Person wird dann ein Ergebnis ausgespuckt. Da mag es regionale Unterschiede geben, aber ein Zufall dürfte das eher nicht sein.

Comment: Ich meinte auch nicht "zufällig", sondern "mit dem sprachlichen Hintergrund des Sprechers am besten vereinbar" - Sprecher sind aber Individuen - Der/Das Joghurt und viele andere Zweifelsfälle zeigen das..

Comment: Karl Kraus zu "der Butter": *Wir würden schon den Butter essen, wenn wir auch eine Schinke hätten*.

Answer (score 4):

Laut der Treffenanzahl auf [*Google Books*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22der%20Skyr%22) ist *Skyr* überwiegend sächlich, kann aber männlich sein. Sicher ist nur, dass es nicht weiblich ist. Das und die Tatsache, dass *Skyr* in Mehrzahl nicht existiert, ist wichtig, weil man sonst anhand der vor dem Nomen stehenden *der*- und die *das*-Treffenanzahl nicht vergleichen könnte (da *der* stünde auch für Genitiv und Dativ weiblich).

Die Frage zum Genus wäre vielleicht zur nächsten (12.) Runde des 
[*Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-11-fragebogen/) angebracht. Verlinkt ist übrigens der Fragebogen zur 11. Runde. Interessant wäre, ob die geographische Genusverteilung, der des Nomens [*Joghurt*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f24a-g/) ähnelt.

Answer (score 2):

Ich finde im Wortfeld der Milchprodukte

weiblich:

- die Butter
- die Milch
- die Molke
- die Sahne

männlich:

- der Joghurt
- der Käse und alle Käsesorten
- der Kefir
- der Quark/der Topfen
- der Schmand

sächlich:

- das Butterschmalz
- das Joghurt
- das Crème fraîche

Das Übergewicht im Gebrauch liegt eindeutig bei weiblich und männlich. Das Butterschmalz ist vom Schmalz abgeleitet und nur deshalb sächlich, *das Joghurt* höre ich praktisch nur von ganz komischen Leuten, und *das Crème fraîche* sagt nur der Profikoch. Schließlich ist *die Creme* ja auch weiblich.

Warum sollte man also *das Skyr* sagen? Aus Kuriosität?

Comment: _Das_ Joghurt statt _der_ Joghurt klingt total seltsam für meine Ohren. Das DWDS gibt an, dass die sächliche Form österreichisch sei.

Comment: *Das Joghurt* kommt wirklich nur in Österreich vor. Nicht mal in Bayern (so weit ich sehe). Ich würde geradezu die These wagen, dass der historische Grund für die staatliche Teilung von Österreich und Deutschland überhaupt nur der Disput über das Genus des Joghurts ist.

Comment: Auch im Schwäbischen ist sowohl *das* als auch *der* Joghurt üblich.

Comment: @Tofro  Dees hanne abbr wyrklich no gar neana gheert, dass oinr "des Jockurt" sait.

Answer (score 2):

Laut [diesem Eintrag auf Wiktionary.org](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Skyr) ist es im Deutschen ein Maskulinum.

Derselbe Artikel gibt an, dass das Wort in der Ursprungssprache Isländisch ein Neutrum ist. Das Genus wurde anscheinend nicht aus der Ursprungssprache übernommen. In anderen Sprachen (Französisch, Spanisch, Polnisch) ist es wie im Deutschen ein Maskulinum.

Ich vermute, dass Skyr im Deutschen männlich ist, weil ähnliche Nahrungsmittel (Joghurt, Quark, Hüttenkäse) ebenfalls maskulin sind.

Comment: Ich finde, man sollte mit Verweisen Wikipedia-Beiträge vorsichtig sein. In diesem Artikel wird zwar behauptet, das Wort sei im Deutschen männlich, es werden aber nur zwei Quellen angebeben: 1) der Wikipedia-Artikel (!) zu Skyr 2) das DWDS. Dort aber findet man für Skyr gar keine Fundstelle im Textkorpus 1900-1999 sowie 2000-2010. Eine einzige Fundstelle mit erkennbarem Genus gibt es im Korpus "Die Zeit": Die Zeit, 14.03.2013, Nr. 12: "Dazu gibt es karamellisierten Skyr, einen fast fettfreien isländischen Quark." Das ist mir etwas zu wenig zur Behauptung, Skyr sei im Deutschen männlich.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Es ist bei Wörtern, die noch nicht so lange eingedeutscht sind (bzw. erst im Begriff sind, eingedeutscht zu werden) etwas schwierig, gute Quellen zu finden. Zwei der anderen Antworten haben derzeit gar keinen Beleg, die dritte verweist auf Google Books... auch irgendwie nicht optimal. Vermutlich müssen wir einfach noch ein paar Jahre warten, bis sich eine Mehrheitsmeinung gebildet und den Weg in den Duden oder ähnlich anerkannte Verzeichnisse gefunden hat...

Comment: Ja, oder wir schreiben hier ganz viel über *den Skyr* und behaupten *der Skyr* müsse männlich sein, weil ein Wort mit -r so männlich klingt (Ausnahme: Mutter, Schwester, Tochter... öh...). Und dann veröffentlichen wir, ganz nach Art der Russen, auch gleich noch die Gegenmeinung, dass *das Skyr* sächlich sein müsse, weil *das Skyr* eben nicht weiter bestimmbaren Geschlechtes sei. Google sammelt dann das hoffentlich alles, und bald haben wir eine schöne Sammlung von Fundstellen sowie eine gespaltene Gesellschaft.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann *das Joghurt* hat es bisher auch noch nicht geschafft, die Gesellschaft zu spalten....

Comment: @tofro   Aber doch! Genau zur Frage des Genus des Joghurts ist die Gesellschaft durchaus gespalten!

Answer (score 1):

Skyr is a foreign word that was unknown in Germany a few years ago. It doesn't have a well established gender.

German loan words may adopt the gender of the original language, if that language has them (like Italian or French). More frequently the gender settles on the gender of its closest German equivalent. (There is a North-South divide in Germany on this practice. I'm no linguist, so I won't go any further.)

The German consumer considers Skyr a yoghurt variety. So, Skyr should adopt the gender of "Jogurt". Unfortunately, that word hasn't a clear gender either. "Jogurt" may be masculine or neuter (or even feminine in Eastern Austria).

Comment: I dissagree on your third sentence.

Comment: @c.p.: Do you mean sentence or paragraph? If you are questioning the third sentence, you might want to read what "Dr. Bopp" at canoo.net (http://canoo.net/blog/2007/09/24/geschlecht-von-fremdwortern/) has to say about it.

Comment: I also disagree on the third paragraph. The German consumer considers Skyr some nordic deity, if anything.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann: Then you should accompany your wife into the supermarket more frequently. :)

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt   For worshipping?

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann:  You'll be able to find the object of your veneration among the milk products. Don't be too disappointed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go by the gender in the original language, Old Norse, see [Cleasby and Vigfússon, 1874](http://lexicon.ff.cuni.cz/png/oi_cleasbyvigfusson/b0563.png) where it is stated as n[euter]. (Unfortunately the easier-to-read transcript, [OCR](http://lexicon.ff.cuni.cz/html/oi_cleasbyvigfusson/b0563.html) has mis-trancribed the gender as "a", which does not help! Asexual? Ambiguous?) However it is clearly neuter as *skyrit* means "das Skyr".

As for what it is, the [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyr) has more information than the German, but I think the important part is

> Skyr is mentioned in a number of medieval Icelandic sources, including Egil's saga and Grettis saga. **It is unclear how similar this was to modern-day skyr, as no detailed descriptions of skyr exist from this period.** Culinary historian Hallgerður Gísladóttir has suggested that skyr was known throughout Scandinavia at the time of the settlement of Iceland, but eventually forgotten outside of Iceland.